# In pytorch, does DataLoader(shuffle=True) really shuffle DBpedia dataset correctly?

Tags: pytorch

According to [the docs](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/datasets.html#dbpedia), DBpedia dataset has 14 classes (labels) and 40000 texts for each class. Then, if I create batches using `DataLoader(shuffle=True)` as follows:

```py
import torchtext.datasets as d
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader

train = DataLoader(
    d.DBpedia(split="train", root=".cache"),
    batch_size=10000,
    shuffle=True,
)
```

the labels should be uniformly distributed in each batch. But in practice, it seems that only a few labels are in each batch.

```py
for labels, texts in train:
    print(len(set(labels.tolist())))
```

The output of the above code is:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
3
3
.
.
.
```

How can I fix this? Or is my implementation wrong?

P.S.
Interactive code is available on [GoogleColab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10524PcR3_spf3fAh37hNbXdLeRVD6Sog?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the shuffling is not working correctly with torchtext datapipes.The [DBpedia documentation](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/_modules/torchtext/datasets/dbpedia.html) states this warning:

> Using datapipes is still currently subject to a few caveats. if you
> wish to use this dataset with shuffling, multi-processing, or
> distributed learning, please see :ref:`this note <datapipes_warnings>`
> for further instructions.
>
> For additional details refer to
> https://www.dbpedia.org/resources/latest-core/

The provided links however do not seem to lead to any solution.

I would suggest converting your DDpedia torchtext datapipe to a standard torch dataset or other format where shuffling works correctly.